# Removing duplicate permission from AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

The `AndroidManifest.xml` contains these (and some more) permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is contained two times. So I remove one and reorder:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

The audio recorder (https://github.com/3llomi/RecordView) normally requests storage access permission and microphone access permission. But after the change it does not request the storage access anymore and therefore the record view does not work.

I uninstall the app from the device for each manifest change to reset permissions.
How is it possible that removing a duplicate line causes this?

Comment: It might have something to do with you requesting READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Try putting that above the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. However, READ is unneeded when WRITE is requested. You should probably just remove it altogether.

Comment: I tried changing the order, same result.

Comment: Then remove the READ permission.

Comment: Removed the read permission - issue still exists.

Comment: Strange. Try putting it at the end.

Comment: The recorder actually still requests the permission to access the microphone. But it does not requests the storage access anymore.

Comment: that RecordView does not request any permissions, at all.

Comment: @MartinZeitler which is probably why it needs the implementer to do so instead.

Answer (score 3):

The merged view of the `AndroidManifest.xml` revealed that another library also declares this permission with `maxSdkVersion="18"`:

[image]

The app was running on API>18, I assume therefore it did not request the permission. Removing `maxSdkVersion` made the storage permission appear again and the recorder view worked:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
```

My guess is that because `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` was contained two times in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, the manifest merging process added the `maxSdkVersion` only to one of them. The other `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` had no `maxSdkVersion` hence the app was requesting the permission also on API>18.